# Header button navigation failed

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation. I try to add a header right navigation button :

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
  title: "My Profile!",
  headerRight: <Button onPress={(navigation)=>{ navigation.navigate('Chat'); }} ><Text>Test</Text></Button>,
});
```

But I get :

> navigation.navigate is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to do

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
  title: "My Profile!",
  headerRight: <Button onPress={()=>{ navigation.navigate('Chat'); }}><Text>Test</Text></Button>,
});
```

Remove the `navigation` from the onPress func parameter.

What you will get from your onPress navigation param is not the navigation object from react-navigation but the touch event object from react-native.